# how to pass Jmeter correlated value to sitespeed.io input as cookie in GitHub actions

Tags: jmeter

I have setup GitHub actions with Jmeter and I would like to validate page load times with Sitespeed.io tool.

So I have created a workflow in which I have included 2 steps.

1. Run jmeter login script and capture Cookie value (Login script include OTP.).
2. Run sitespeed.io docker image by passing --Cookie value along with URL.

I have correlated cookie value in jmeter and saved "`c_Cookie`" param(jmeter parameter).

How to pass this cookie value to sitespeed.io tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running JMeter and "sitespeed.io" (whatever it is) in different jobs you can:

1. Store the cookie value into the file using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

   ```
   new File('cookie.txt').text = vars.get('c_Cookie')
   ```
2. Store the file as the job artifact
3. Use `cookie.txt` file in your "sitespeed.io" job

More information: [Passing data between jobs in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow)

Comment: Thank you Dimitri. Its working fine as expected. But I am unable to pass the cookie value within the steps. So i created 2 Jobs.
In 1st Job, with jmeter login script saved Cookie values in a file.
in 2nd job, I have download the Cookie file and save the value in GitHub env variable and pass that variable as input to Sitespeed.io tool.